# Load changed content via jQuery inside page

Tags: javascript, jquery

i Have this:

```
<div style='display:none' id='myDiv'>
  <input type='text' value='' id='text1'>
  <input type='text' value='' id='text2'>
<div>

<ul>
<li> <a href="#" onClick="$('#text1').val('Hello1');
                          $('#text2').val('Hello2');">Load content</a>
   <span id='divLoader'></span> 
</li>
</ul>
```

And I Want to load into `#divLoader`, content from Div `#myDiv` , but with `#text1` and `#text2` displayed and if i had more `a links` it will change equal.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm sorry can you make this more clear. What event triggers information to be loaded into #divLoader? and what do you want to be loaded into #divLoader?

Comment: I want load Content in `myDiv`, into `divLoader`, but with .val(), it doesnt work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div style='display:none' id='myDiv'>
  <input type='text' value='' id='text1'/>
  <input type='text' value='' id='text2'/>
</div>

<ul>
<li> <a href="#" onClick="$('#text1').val('Hello1');
                          $('#text2').val('Hello2');
                          $('#divLoader').html($('#myDiv').html());">Load content</a>
   <span id='divLoader'></span> 
</li>
</ul>
```

but it's better to put that code into `<script>` tag

```
$(function() {
   $('ul li a').click(function() {
       $('#text1').val('Hello1');
       $('#text2').val('Hello2');
       $('#divLoader').html($('#myDiv').html());
   });
});
```

Comment: @user1958457 It seams that `val()` don't modify attribute, try this http://jsfiddle.net/Qa5S4/6/

Comment: Thanks !, it works!, yes `.val()` seems doesn't work, I'll use `.attr()`. Thanks again.

Comment: Please, change second <div> ending, and add a slash I forget it.